# MPAndroidChart - Horizontal bar chart - Justify label text to the left

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using MPAndroidChart to create a horizontal bar graph.

Is it possible to justify the label text from the left as opposed to the right?

[image]

Code:

```
mChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new LabelValueFormatter(set1));
            mChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM_INSIDE);
            mChart.getXAxis().setXOffset(100);
```

Comment: I think you can make it by putting space before the label in your Values formatter... But I think there is a more proper way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Setting the axis position to the TOP and reversing the offset worked:

```
mChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new LabelValueFormatter(set1));
mChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.TOP);
mChart.getXAxis().setXOffset(-350);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set to draw the values above the bars by:

```
mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
```

[the result is like this image.](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/2ec281e0ac3013076bff1c3ac00d8d6de372d7a4/68747470733a2f2f7261772e6769746875622e636f6d2f5068696c4a61792f4d5043686172742f6d61737465722f73637265656e73686f74732f686f72697a6f6e74616c5f62617263686172742e706e67)

Comment: Is it possible to have LEFT gravity for the labels? @shabnam-esmaeili

Comment: I don't think so @AndrewS